# Black and white view after splitting window

Tags: edit-mode

I have a huge problem (I'm new in blender so it maybe be something stupid actually), after splitting the windows and go back to only one view window, I can not see colors anymore. At the beginning, when splitting the window, the left window is normal (with colors if you had an object or something with a color material) and in the right window you had a black and white image. Ok, after joining the windows I only have forever and ever the black and white view :/, the only way for me to see the material's colors is to render the image. I even  tried to delete and reinstall Blender (2.8 and 2.81a) but I still the black and white view. Can someone help me with this issue?

[image: Split view]

[image: render image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the issue is that you are in **Solid** view and want to see the **Material Preview**.

Click this button at the top right of the 3D viewport and you will see the material attached to the object.

[image: Shading mode]

As an aside, you can change the color of objects in **Solid** shading mode by scrolling down towards the bottom of the Material Properties tab and choosing a color for the object under **Viewport Display**.